Is pasting limited comments of others to ChatGPT fair use?
Related: What is your goal when asking ChatGPT to assess the comments received in reply to your question?
A user excerpted selected comments from other users and pasted them to ChatGPT, asking ChatGPT for its response to these comments. The user then added links to these transcripts on the same question.
Another user suggested that this could be a CC-BY-SA licensing violation. The user deleted their comments about this when questioned. But I think this needs to be discussed because I have since received flags alleging that this content violates CC-BY-SA and asking to delete it on that basis.
CC-BY-SA 4.0, under which stackexchange user content is licensed to everyone, allows duplication in any form for any purpose as long as attribution is provided and the duplicated content is also licensed under CC-BY-SA 4.0, and this license is linked. These are not onerous terms; to comply you would simply need to make sure to mention the names of every user you quoted, and then link to the license. It appears this was not done, although I don't think anything stops the user from adding those elements to the end of the ChatGPT transcript to bring it into compliance.
Is it fair use or fair dealing?
Fair use is a US legal doctrine which allows for short excerpts of a work to be used without any license for the purpose of nonprofit commentary or criticism. That is what was done, so it is an instance of fair use, and therefore the terms of CC-BY-SA need not be complied with. This is only relevant if the user is US-based.
Fair dealing is a similar doctrine in many other countries, which also permits use of portions of a work for study or criticism, without needing to comply with the terms of any license.

I am a fallibilist; I am always open to the idea that I may have been mistaken.

The question should clarify whether the pasting itself is contentious, or the generation of public transcripts (without links). Also this question seems relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270014 and it would be useful if this question did a similar research on meta SE for similar issues.

Comments might not even qualify as content that can be copyrighted, see https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/87627 . Then technically it would not even be fair use of copyrighted material, but use of copyright-free material.

Italy fines OpenAI €15 million for privacy violations in ChatGPT data use

The question presents the moderator conclusion:

so it is an instance of fair use, and therefore the terms of CC-BY-SA need not be complied with

I am assuming the question author is a moderator, since they say they are responding to flagged comments.
If this is the position moderators have come to through a legal analysis or legal advice, so be it. Thank you for telling us, moderator team. I accept your position.

No, this is a discussion question for the community.

I'm telling you how I see it at present. (and only me; I have not consulted other moderators.) This question is the consultation. If there is a sufficiently strong legal argument for why it's not fair use, I am ready to hear it.

@MisterMiyagi I think Lowri's browser is running special scripts that hide usernames, purposefully so to prevent herself from being biased by usernames.

why are you continuously removing your comments if you are interested in honest discussion?
